# geom_point with different legend for fill and shape

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hmmm, maybe it's the temprature or I'm once again do not see the obvious ...

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x = 1, y=1,bg = "I", group = "B"),pch = 21, size = 20, color=NA)
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x = 1, y=1.125,bg = "I", group = "B" ),pch = 22, size = 20, color=NA)
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x = 0.75, y=1.125,bg = "II", group = "A" ),pch = 22, size = 20, color=NA)
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x = 0.85, y=1.125,bg = "III", group = "A" ),pch = 22, size = 20, color=NA)
p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values= c("darkred", "darkblue", "darkgreen"), guide=guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 23)))
#p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values= c("darkred", "darkblue", "darkgreen"), guide=guide_legend(inherit.aes = FALSE))
p <- p + scale_shape_manual(labels = c("circle", "rectangle"),values = c(21, 22))
p
```

What I'm trying to achieve are basically two legends, one that reflects the color, in this example there are three different colors ("I", "II", and "III"), and two different types of shapes "rectangle" and "circle", there will never be more than these two different shapes.

Unfortunately there are some additional constraints ... I can't use the aesthetic `color` due to the fact that I'm also using `geom_segment` to somehow connect the shapes, and that is the second constraint, I have to use ggplot2.

But I'not able to produce these two legends, any help is appreciated ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you store all your points in a data frame? It suits perfectly:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 1, 0.75, 0.85), 
                 y = c(1, 1.125, 1.125, 1.125), 
                 nr = c("I", "I", "II", "III"), 
                 sh = c("B", "B", "A", "A"))
```

And now you can easily see the required mapping:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = nr, shape = sh)) + 
  geom_point(size = 20, color = NA) + 
  scale_shape_manual(labels = c("circle", "rectangle"), values = c(21, 22), 
                     guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = 1))) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkred", "darkblue", "darkgreen"), 
                    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 23)))
```

[image]

Comment: @tonytonv I have to admit that I have a data.frame (to be precise a data.table) but for some obvious reason I missed something, looking at my code and posting the result :-) thanks a lot